# AWS Route53 - use load balancer to redirect for all subdomains but one

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have a complicated scenario where I need to redirect domain requests to another domain for some requests but stay in the original domain for others.

For example, if I had [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com):

I want to route [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com) to [www.abc.app](http://www.abc.app). Or if the user types in [www.abc.com/hello](http://www.abc.com/hello) then it will route to [www.abc.app/hello](http://www.abc.app/hello). This is currently done via load balancer and creating an "A" record in Route53 connected to the load balancer

BUT I want to reserve a specific subdomain. Let's say if the user types in [www.abc.com/game](http://www.abc.com/game), then I want it to display a NodeJS application that's hosted in a separate EC2 server. The domain will not change and it will remain as [www.abc.com/game](http://www.abc.com/game).

Is this at all possible to do if the "A" record is already being taken by the load balancer?

Answer (score 0):

No. **This is not possible to do with DNS.**

DNS servers simply convert the domain name (`www.abc.com`) to an IP address. The 'path' portion (`/game`) is not sent to the DNS servers, so they cannot use that to change the DNS resolution process.

You will either need to:

- Use different sub-domains (eg `game.abc.com`), or
- Send all traffic to one location and then have the receiving service figure out how to process the requests, or
- Use [URL Rewriting With Lambda@Edge | smarx.com](https://smarx.com/posts/2020/08/url-rewriting-with-lambda-at-edge/), which can 'intercept' the request and rewrite it, which could send the request to a different location or tell the user's web browser to send the request to a different location

Answer (score 0):

You could use an application load balancer and path based routing.
https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/elb-achieve-path-based-routing-alb

If your node app were amplify, you could use path based routing to /games.
https://docs.amplify.aws/javascript/build-a-backend/restapi/configure-rest-api/

You could use api gateway. Check out the Routing API requests, section.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-routes.html

You could use CloudFront origins, too.
https://hitaha.medium.com/path-based-routing-on-aws-cloudfront-host-multiple-amplify-and-s3-apps-under-one-domain-3d47dda9e2c3